# Android studio imports the old version of support library

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

Though I use `26.1.0` version in gradle, Android studio still imports the old version of support library.

It started since I copied a class from another project where was `25.2.0` version. Now when I try to import `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` somewhere in my project, it always imports 25.2.0.

I tried to remove all the v4 Fragment dependencies in my project and import them again but no success - Android Studio still offers me to choose between `Fragment Android API 26` and `support-fragment-25.2.0`. 
There is `com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0` in the project's gradle file.

How to resolve this problem?
Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.